# Allow whitespace after comma in regex pattern validation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying pattern validation for my input field.

```
^(OTC[0-9]{1,99})(,OTC[0-9]{1,99})*$
```

For the above pattern following inputs are valid:

```
OTC123,OTC567,OTC987
```

but I also want to allow whitespaces after commas:

```
OTC123,   OTC567,   OTC987.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: So, just add `\s?` or `\s*` at those locations in the pattern where you want to "allow" whitespaces.

Comment: I tried     ^(OTC[0-9]{1,99})(,\s*OTC[0-9]{1,99})*$ but did not work

Comment: You can use the \s flag for capture white space and the ? after 
\s? matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
try this one mate
```^(OTC[0-9]{1,99})(,\s?OTC[0-9]{1,99})*$```

Comment: Even ^(OTC[0-9]{1,99})(,\s?OTC[0-9]{1,99})*$ i is not working

Comment: [**It works**](https://regex101.com/r/pt0cmk/1). `/^OTC[0-9]{1,99}(?:,\s*OTC[0-9]{1,99})*$/.test("OTC123,   OTC567,   OTC987")` works, too.

Comment: Well I solved the prob by just adding [ ]* to allow Whitespace...thnk you for ur help